# Brownian motion: Why $p\{-x\leq B_t\leq x \mid B_{t_n}=\pm x_n,...,B_{t_1}=\pm x_1\}=p\{-x\leq B_t\leq x\mid B_{t_n}=x_n,...,B_{t_1}=x_1\}$

Tags: brownian-motion

Let $(B_t)$ be a Brownian motion. Why:
$$p\{-x\leq B_t\leq x \mid B_{t_n}=\pm x_n,...,B_{t_1}=\pm x_1\}=p\{-x\leq B_t\leq x\mid B_{t_n}=x_n,...,B_{t_1}=x_1\}\ \ \ ?$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming $t > t_n$ you can reduced your relationship to

$$p\{-x\leq B_t\leq x \mid B_{t_n}=\pm x_n\}=p\{-x\leq B_t\leq x\mid B_{t_n}=x_n\}$$

because $B_t$ is Markov.

I'll proceed formally:
\begin{eqnarray*}
p\{-x\leq B_t\leq x \mid B_{t_n}=\pm x_n\} &=& \frac{p\{-x\leq B_t\leq x \text{ and } B_{t_n}=\pm x_n\}}{p\{B_{t_n}=\pm x_n\}} \\
&=& \frac{2p\{-x\leq B_t\leq x \text{ and } B_{t_n}= x_n\}}{2p\{B_{t_n}= x_n\}} \\
&=& p\{-x\leq B_t\leq x\mid B_{t_n}=x_n\} \\
\end{eqnarray*}

Comment: I just don't understand why: $$\frac{p\{-x\leq B_t\leq x \text{ and } B_{t_n}=\pm x_n\}}{p\{B_{t_n}=\pm x_n\}} 
=\frac{2p\{-x\leq B_t\leq x \text{ and } B_{t_n}= x_n\}}{2p\{B_{t_n}= x_n\}}$$ Thanks

Comment: @idm  Those both follow from Brownian Motion being symmetric about the origin.  If $B_t(\omega)$ is a path then so is $-B_t(\omega)$.  Alternatively, $-B_t$ is a Brownian Motion.